# ajax response from PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm being a bit of an idiot and seem to be unable to find an answer to my question, I am wanting to send a search request to my PHP file and return results, when I do that I can't seem to do the right thing, I'm definitely using the correct file but I'm not sure how to return results from the PHP file (I'm fairly new to ajax this so I do apologies for sound silly)

Jquery/Ajax:

```
    $('#searchGo').click(function() {
        var tempVar = 0;
        var request = $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: "/../commerce/search.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "search=" + $('#search').val(),
            dataType: "html"
        });
        alert(request.responseText + ' test');
    });
```

Search.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    return 'yes';
}
return 'no';
```

And the response text isn't giving me anything, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check your firebug console

Comment: `async: false` is definitely something wrong (although not the main issue here). It is also deprecated since jQuery 1.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `echo` not `return`.

The JS is reading the HTTP response. So you need to respond with some data, not just return it to the calling (PHP) function.

Comment: Thank you so much, will accept answer after timeout period, much appreicated!

Answer (score 2):

instead of returning, call

use

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    echo 'yes';
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `echo`, in function you use `return`

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    echo 'yes';
}
echo 'no';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    echo 'yes';
}
echo 'no';
```